# Is it possible to construct a radiography instrument that images in the radiofrequency band?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I am wondering if one can extend the radiography outside the visible range (ordinary cameras), X-ray band (x-ray photos),  IR-band (infrared images), and microwave region. Can one construct imaging units that capture images in the other regions such as the lower-energy range of radiofrequencies?

Thanks

Comment: Radar mapping is a thing, e.g. synthetic aperture radar. The surface of Venus has been mapped by radar. So, clearly the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this

Comment: This instrument makes images from radio waves. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Bank_Telescope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but the diffraction limited resolution of such a system is about half a wavelength. The wavelength at 100 MHz (not a terribly low radio frequency) is 3 meters.

Answer (score 2):

What John Doty said (+1). But you can beat the diffraction limit. Put the patient behind a screen with a hole in it. A little of the radar wave will pass through. Move the screen around so the hole scans over the patient. A fuzzy image could be build up.

But the real question is what medically important information would a radar image provide?

There is a better way. Radar frequencies are used in MRI, together with a strong magnetic field. The radar beam doesn't directly image the patient.

Protons have a small magnetic moment. In a magnetic field, they can align either parallel to the field or anti-parallel. The anti-parallel orientation is lower energy, so that is the orientation most wind up in.

Like electrons in an atom, light can excite a transition to the higher state. The energy difference is small, so this light is in at radio frequency. The frequency depends on the environment immediately around the proton. That is, different atomic nuclei have different transition frequencies. Smaller differences are found when the nuclei are in different chemical environments.

In MRI, the radio frequency is chosen to align hydrogen nuclei, which are abundant in water and fat.

The aligned nuclei cause a small magnetic field. Measuring gradients in this field allows the MRI machine to build up an image of where these nuclei are.

The radar beam is switched off. Aligned nuclei decay back to the anti-parallel configuration, emitting radio frequency light as they do. Detectors measure this light and the decay time. The decay time can be used to differentiate between different tissues.

See [Physics of magnetic resonance imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_magnetic_resonance_imaging) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called *radar*. very handy for finding ships and planes of size ~tens of meters. Not so good for finding things of size ~millimeters as John Doty points out. but ultrasound imaging is good for that.

Comment: What if a source, like a radio, is emitting radio frequencies. Would this look like "rays emerging from a point" from ma radar perspective, if the radio is big enough? For instance, a radiogalaxy, it would emit radiowaves, but from specific areas. Can these be narrow and "zoomed" in at?